# How can I create this API with JavaScript and break out the methods

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, api-design

Let's say I wanted to have this API for an example to do app:

```
var db = new Database('db-name'); // DB connection
var todo = new Todo(db); // New "Todo" and pass it the DB ref
// I want this API:
todo.model.create('do this', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I have it setup currently like:

```
function Todo (storage) {
  this.storage = storage;
};

Todo.prototype.model = {
  create: function (task, callback) {
    // The problem is "this" is Todo.model
    // I want the "super", or Todo so I can do:
    this.storage.save(task, callback);
  }
}
```

So, if you see the comment, the problem is that "`this`" inside of `model.create` is obviously referencing `Todo.model`, but I need it to grab the "`super`".

Best I could think of was:

```
Todo.prototype.model = function () {
  var self = this;
  return {
    create: function (task, callback) {
      // The problem is "this" is Todo.model
      // I want the "super", or Todo so I can do:
      self.storage.save(task, callback);
    }
  }
}
```

But both of these aren't great. The biggest problem is that I don't want to have all my methods on `model` inside of a single object (1st example) or function (2nd). I want to be able to take them out  from inside of the model def. Secondly, I'd like to have the `todo.model.create` API.

Is there a design pattern to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the prototype pattern for `todo.model` as you've written it because `model` is a *property* of `todo`.

I think you need:

1. a new `Model` object, on which you *can* use the prototype model.
2. in the `Todo` constructor, create a `Model` object.  Ideally, use a read-only "getter" function to allow that model object to be accessed, but not overwritten.

Comment: Seems to work and allows me to break all the model methods out and I get the API I wanted. Good idea. I feel like the `Model` "class" is sort of floating in space tho since it's not inherited from anything or attached to anything, but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `bind`, you can do something like this:

```
function Todo (storage) {
  this.storage = storage;
  this.model = {};

  var methodNames = Object.keys(TodoModel);

  for(var i = 0; i < methodNames.length; ++i) {
    var methodName = methodNames[i];
    var method = TodoModel[methodNames];

    model[methodName] = method.bind(this);
  }
};

var TodoModel = {
  create: function(task, callback) {
    // Note that when this method is called using Todo.model.create,
    // 'this' will point to the Todo instance.
    this.storage.save(task, callback);
  }
};

function test(storage) {
  var todo = new Todo(storage);
  var task = {};

  todo.model.create(task, function(err, savedTask) {
    // ...
  });
}
```

The `TodoModel` is basically a map, so you can replace it with a Map collection and you will no longer need to call `Object.keys`.

Comment: Thanks! You should have just put this in your other answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could set up the `model` in the constructor like in the following example:

```
function Todo (storage) {
  var self = this;

  this.storage = storage;

  this.model = {
    create: function(task, callback) {
      self.storage.save(task, callback);
    }
  };
};
```

Alternatively, you could use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), but I think that it would unnecessarily complicate things, because you must find an implementation that works on older browsers and it does not conflict with the native implementation in newer browsers that support EcmaScript 5.

Comment: IE9 support is fine. I don't care about IE<=8. How would I use bind in this case to create the API I'd like? Is there anyway to breakout model tho? My constructor could end up growing huge with all my models, views, etc inside.